# How to change the default device in cuPy?

Tags: python, gpu, cupy

I am using cuPy in a python program to perform computations on GPU. My program consists of several functions/classes spread across multiple files.

I am using a GPU cluster (NVIDIA V100), consisting of four GPUs.

How can I select a particular GPU as the default GPU for the whole program? I found some information at [**cuPy documentation**](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.cuda.Device.html#cupy.cuda.Device.use) about `use` keyword but since there is no example, I am not sure how to utilize it.

**MWE:**

> maths_ops.py:

```
import cupy as cp

class MathsOps:
    def vector_addition(self, vector1, vector2):
        return cp.add(vector1, vector2)
```

> dummy_class.py:

```
from maths_ops import MathsOps

class DummyClass:
    def __init__(self, maths_ops_instance):
        self.maths_ops_instance = maths_ops_instance

    def perform_operation(self, vector1, vector2):
        result = self.maths_ops_instance.vector_addition(vector1, vector2)
        return result
```

> main.py:

```
from maths_ops import MathsOps
from dummy_class import DummyClass

# Create an instance of MathsOps
maths_ops_instance = MathsOps()

# Create an instance of DummyClass with the MathsOps instance
dummy_instance = DummyClass(maths_ops_instance)

# Example vectors
vector1 = cp.array([1, 2, 3])
vector2 = cp.array([4, 5, 6])

# Perform vector addition using DummyClass
result = dummy_instance.perform_operation(vector1, vector2)

# Print the result
print("Vector Addition Result:", result)
```

**Question:** How do I specify a GPU device (for example, device-1) I'm the `main` function as the default GPU device that should be used by the program?

Comment: https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.cuda.Device.html#cupy-cuda-device

Comment: @talonmies: It's the link to the same page that I provided in my post too. I can switch to a different GPU device by putting some code under the `with cupy.cuda.Device(device_id)` but in that case, the default GPU is automatically selected as soon as we come out of the `with` block. I am looking for a way to select a different GPU device-id (default is 0) as the default GPU for the whole program i.e. to avoid cluttering my program with a lot of `with`-blocks eveywhere.

Comment: The `Device` object has a `.use()` method if you don't wanna use it as a context manager.